# Class Declarations for temperature program in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, declaration, temperature

So this is the problem I'm having I need to input these five methods:

- Temperature – a constructor method. This should set the initial temperature to 100.
- getTemp – a method to return the current stored value of degrees Celsius
- convertToF – a method to convert a Celsius temperature to degrees Fahrenheit
- convertToK – a method to convert a Celsius temperature to degrees Kelvin
- updateTempC – a method to update the stored temperature in degrees Celsius

into this program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempProg {



public static void main(String[] args)
{

    // Declare objects
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Temperature tempConv = new Temperature();

    // Declare variables
    int newTemp;
    boolean entryValid;

    // Declare constants
    final int MIN_TEMP = -273;
    final int MAX_TEMP = 10000;

    System.out.println("\tTemperature converter");

    // Set a dummy selection value, so that we always show the options on the first go
    char selection = 'x';

    // Offer a list of options
    while (selection != 'q') { 
        System.out.println("\n\tCurrent temperature in degrees C: " + tempConv.getTemp());
        System.out.println("\tType f to display temperature in Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("\tType k to display temperature in Kelvin");
        System.out.println("\tType c to set a new temperature");
        System.out.println("\tType q to quit");

        // Read from the keyboard
        selection = scan.next().charAt(0);


        // Act on the selection
        switch(selection) {
            case 'f': // Print Fahrenheit version
                System.out.println("\n\t" +tempConv.getTemp()+ " degrees C = "+tempConv.convertToF() +" degrees F" );
                break;

            case 'k': // Print Kelvin version 
                System.out.println("\n\t" +tempConv.getTemp()+ " degrees C = "+tempConv.convertToK() +" degrees K" );
                break;

            case 'c': // Get a new temperature

                entryValid=false; // Reset entryValid for this round

                /* test for !entryValid
                 * i.e. "not entryValid"
                 * i.e. same as "entryValid == false"
                 */

                while (!entryValid) { // This will always be true the first time
                    System.out.print("\n\tPlease enter a new temperature: ");
                    newTemp = scan.nextInt();

                    // Check validity of new temperature
                    if (newTemp < MIN_TEMP || newTemp > MAX_TEMP) {
                        System.out.println("\tPlease enter a valid temperature");
                    } else {
                        entryValid=true;
                        tempConv.updateTempC(newTemp);
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 'q': // Don't do anything for q, we print a message later
                break;

            default: // If it is not f, k, c or q then default is error message
                System.out.println("\n\tOption " + selection + " not understood");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n\tPROGRAM ENDED");
}
}
```

and this is what I have so far...

```
private double Temperature (double currentTemp)
    {
        currentTemp = 100;
        return currentTemp;

    }

    public double convertToF (double TempF)
    {
        TempF = ((9 * currentTemp) / 5 ) + 32;
        return TempF();
    }

    public double convertToK (double TempK)
    {
        TempK = currentTemp + 273;
        return TempK();
    }

    public void updateTempC (double currentTemp)
    {
        newTemp = currentTemp;

        return currentTemp();
    }

    public double getTemp()
    {
        return currentTemp;
     }
```

it is basically won't compile and I'm 99% sure it's very wrong and I literally have no idea what to do... thoughts... suggestions?

and errors are:

```
    tempProg.java:14: error: class TempProg is public, should be declared in a file named            TempProg.java
public class TempProg {
       ^
    tempProg.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
            TempF = ((9 * currentTemp) / 5 ) + 32;
                          ^
  symbol:   variable currentTemp
  location: class TempProg
    tempProg.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            return TempF();
                   ^
  symbol:   method TempF()
  location: class TempProg
    tempProg.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
            TempK = currentTemp + 273;
                    ^
  symbol:   variable currentTemp
  location: class TempProg
    tempProg.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
            return TempK();
                   ^
  symbol:   method TempK()
  location: class TempProg
    tempProg.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
            newTemp = currentTemp;
            ^
  symbol:   variable newTemp
  location: class TempProg
    tempProg.java:40: error: cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
            return currentTemp();
                              ^
    tempProg.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
            return currentTemp;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable currentTemp
  location: class TempProg
    tempProg.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        Temperature tempConv = new Temperature();
        ^
  symbol:   class Temperature
  location: class TempProg
    tempProg.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        Temperature tempConv = new Temperature();
                                   ^
  symbol:   class Temperature
  location: class TempProg
```

Comment: What is your question?  I really can't make sense of "it is basically having none of it".

Comment: like the program will not compile at all and I don't know what to dooooooo!

Comment: @marianna013 Show us the errors and there locations.

Comment: Presumably you have been taught how to write a constructor in Java, or why would you have been set this exercise. Either look at the examples in your notes, or if you don't have any, Google "Java constructor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Temperature` class. I'm just guessing that you've added those methods to the `TempProg` considering the improper "constructor". What you need is another class all together like so...

```
public class Temperature {
  // Put those method and data members here
}
```

The constructor should not return a value. It should look like... `public Temperature()`, or some variation depending on your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**OUTPUT**
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYqs2.jpg)

> Default temperatures: 0.0C OR 32.0F
>
> 1.Convert Celcius to Fareiheit
>
> 2.Convert Fareiheit to Celcius
>
> 3.Update default temperature
>
> 1
>
> Enter temperature in Celcius to convert into Farenheit
>
> 60
>
> 60.0C = 92.0F
>
> Default temperatures: 0.0C OR 32.0F
>
> 1.Convert Celcius to Fareiheit
>
> 2.Convert Fareiheit to Celcius
>
> 3.Update default temperature
>
> 2
>
> Enter temperature in Farenheit to convert into Celcius
>
> -10
>
> -10.0F = -23.333333333333336C
>
> Default temperatures: 0.0C OR 32.0F
>
> 1.Convert Celcius to Fareiheit
>
> 2.Convert Fareiheit to Celcius
>
> 3.Update default temperature
>
> 3
>
> Enter temperature in celcius
>
> 25
>
> Default temperatures: 25.0C OR 57.0F
>
> 1.Convert Celcius to Fareiheit
>
> 2.Convert Fareiheit to Celcius
>
> 3.Update default temperature

---

**Temperature.java**

```
public interface Temperature {
    public double getTempInFarenheit(double celcius);
    public double getTempInCelcius(double farenheit);
    public double getCurrentTemp();
    public double setDefaultTemp(double defaultCelcius);
    }
```

**TemperatureImpl.java**

```
public class TemperatureImpl implements Temperature {

    private double defaultTemp=0.0;

    public double Temperature(double defaultTemp){
        return this.defaultTemp=defaultTemp;
    }

    @Override
    public double getTempInFarenheit(double celcius) {
        return ((double)(9/5)*(celcius+32.0));
    }

    @Override
    public double getTempInCelcius(double farenheit) {
        return ((double)5/9*(farenheit-32.0));
    }

    @Override
    public double getCurrentTemp() {
        return defaultTemp;
    }

    @Override
    public double setDefaultTemp(double defaultCelcius){
        return this.defaultTemp = defaultCelcius;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TemperatureImpl temp = new TemperatureImpl();

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Default temperatures: "+temp.getCurrentTemp()+"C OR "+temp.getTempInFarenheit(temp.getCurrentTemp())+"F");
            System.out.println("1.Convert Celcius to Fareiheit");
            System.out.println("2.Convert Fareiheit to Celcius");
            System.out.println("3.Update default temperature");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = sc.nextInt();
            switch (input) {
            case 1: System.out.println("Enter temperature in Celcius to convert into Farenheit");
                double celcius = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(celcius+"C = "+temp.getTempInFarenheit(celcius)+"F");
                break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Enter temperature in Farenheit to convert into Celcius");
            double fareinheit = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(fareinheit+"F = "+temp.getTempInCelcius(fareinheit)+"C");
            break;
            case 3: System.out.println("Enter temperature in celcius");
            temp.setDefaultTemp(sc.nextDouble());
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");;
            }

        }
    }
}
```