# Java OOP Temperature Converter

Tags: java, oop

I'm fairly new at Java, even newer at trying to understand *OOP*, so don't make fun of my lack of understanding, please.

I'm trying to design a program that will get the user to input a temperature in either *Fahrenheit* or *Celsius*, then the program will determine what that temperature is in the other measurement.

Can anyone give me any tips on if I am even going in the right direction?

This is what I have so far, and keep in mind that this is pretty much my first attempt at *OOP*, so it probably looks like a mess.

```
import java.io.*;

class tempConvert
 {

//declaring variables
int c;      //variable for "Celcius"
int f;      //variable for "Fahrenheit"




//method to convert celcius to fahrenheit
public void celToFahr
 {
  InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
  BufferedReader temp = new BufferedReader (inStream);
  String cel;
  System.out.println ("Please input temperature in celcius:");
  cel = temp.readLine ( );
  c = Integer.parseInt (cel);

  f = (9.0 / 5.0) * c + 32;

  System.out.println ("The temperature in Fahrenheit is " + f + " degrees.");
 }




//method to convert fahrenheit to celcius
public void fahrToCel
 {
  BufferedReader temp = new BufferedReader (inStream);
  String fahr;
  System.out.println ("Please input temperature in fahrenheit:");
  fahr = temp.readLine ( );
  f = Integer.parseInt (fahr);

  c = (5.0 / 9.0) * (f - 32);

  System.out.println ("The temperature in Celcius is " + c + " degrees.");
 }



  }
```

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to determine from a temperature what scale it is in.  For example, if I input 0, which is it?  What about 32?  You would need some way to identify which type it is

Comment: It's worth noting, that there are no OOP concepts in this code

Comment: IMO I would ask for guidance in a more 'regular' Java programming forum with a 'new to java' section rather than in this Q&A oriented site.

Comment: In order to better understand OOP in Java, have a look at online tutorials abound on the web, e.g., this one: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3a_OOPBasics.html. If you then encounter more specific issues, you are welcome to come back and ask here :).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an OOP concept you could use: *value types*.  Value types are objects that hold a value like the primitive wrappers Integer, Double, etc., and other classes like BigDecimal.

Now, here are three ideas for your value type: 1) One class that has two fields to represent the value and the scale; 2) A different class for every temperature scale; 3) One class that internally always represents the temperature using the same scale and externally converts it to other scales.  When choosing one of these designs, ponder the complexity of the conversion methods you will have to write, and the complexity of client code that would use the little API you are creating, especially if you ever wanted to add support for more temperature scales.

Answer (score 0):

**OUTPUT**
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYqs2.jpg)

> Default temperatures: 0.0C OR 32.0F
>
> 1.Convert Celcius to Fareiheit
>
> 2.Convert Fareiheit to Celcius
>
> 3.Update default temperature
>
> 1
>
> Enter temperature in Celcius to convert into Farenheit
>
> 60
>
> 60.0C = 92.0F
>
> Default temperatures: 0.0C OR 32.0F
>
> 1.Convert Celcius to Fareiheit
>
> 2.Convert Fareiheit to Celcius
>
> 3.Update default temperature
>
> 2
>
> Enter temperature in Farenheit to convert into Celcius
>
> -10
>
> -10.0F = -23.333333333333336C
>
> Default temperatures: 0.0C OR 32.0F
>
> 1.Convert Celcius to Fareiheit
>
> 2.Convert Fareiheit to Celcius
>
> 3.Update default temperature
>
> 3
>
> Enter temperature in celcius
>
> 25
>
> Default temperatures: 25.0C OR 57.0F
>
> 1.Convert Celcius to Fareiheit
>
> 2.Convert Fareiheit to Celcius
>
> 3.Update default temperature

---

**Temperature.java**

```
public interface Temperature {
    public double getTempInFarenheit(double celcius);
    public double getTempInCelcius(double farenheit);
    public double getCurrentTemp();
    public double setDefaultTemp(double defaultCelcius);
    }
```

**TemperatureImpl.java**

```
public class TemperatureImpl implements Temperature {

    private double defaultTemp=0.0;

    public double Temperature(double defaultTemp){
        return this.defaultTemp=defaultTemp;
    }

    @Override
    public double getTempInFarenheit(double celcius) {
        return ((double)(9/5)*(celcius+32.0));
    }

    @Override
    public double getTempInCelcius(double farenheit) {
        return ((double)5/9*(farenheit-32.0));
    }

    @Override
    public double getCurrentTemp() {
        return defaultTemp;
    }

    @Override
    public double setDefaultTemp(double defaultCelcius){
        return this.defaultTemp = defaultCelcius;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TemperatureImpl temp = new TemperatureImpl();

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Default temperatures: "+temp.getCurrentTemp()+"C OR "+temp.getTempInFarenheit(temp.getCurrentTemp())+"F");
            System.out.println("1.Convert Celcius to Fareiheit");
            System.out.println("2.Convert Fareiheit to Celcius");
            System.out.println("3.Update default temperature");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = sc.nextInt();
            switch (input) {
            case 1: System.out.println("Enter temperature in Celcius to convert into Farenheit");
                double celcius = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(celcius+"C = "+temp.getTempInFarenheit(celcius)+"F");
                break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Enter temperature in Farenheit to convert into Celcius");
            double fareinheit = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(fareinheit+"F = "+temp.getTempInCelcius(fareinheit)+"C");
            break;
            case 3: System.out.println("Enter temperature in celcius");
            temp.setDefaultTemp(sc.nextDouble());
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not post the same answer multiple times. You already posted this here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36969922/1743880.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the whole thing all over again since as said in the comments you did not write in OOP:

This is the main OOP part, a class that creates objects of temperature.

package com.example.tomer2;

```
public class temp {
    double c; // for celcius
    double f; // for farenheit
    boolean isfarenheit;

    public temp( double temp , boolean isfarenheit) {
        if(isfarenheit){
            this.f = temp;
            this.c = this.farenToCelc(temp);
        }
        else{
            this.c = temp;
            this.f = this.celciusToFar(temp);
        }
    }

    private double celciusToFar(double celcius){
        return ((double)(9/5)*(celcius+32.0));
    }

    public double farenToCelc(double farenheit) {
        return ((double)5/9*(farenheit-32.0));
    }


}
```

Here is the class with the main function:

```
package com.example.tomer2;

public class temp {
    double c; // for celcius
    double f; // for farenheit
    boolean isfarenheit;

    public temp( double temp , boolean isfarenheit) {
        if(isfarenheit){
            this.f = temp;
            this.c = this.farenToCelc(temp);
        }
        else{
            this.c = temp;
            this.f = this.celciusToFar(temp);
        }
    }

    private double celciusToFar(double celcius){
        return ((double)(9/5)*(celcius+32.0));
    }

    public double farenToCelc(double farenheit) {
        return ((double)5/9*(farenheit-32.0));
    }


}
```

I did not do complete tests for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using encapsulation fields,

```
Public class Temp{
  private double cel;
  private double far;

  public double getCel(){
    return ((far-32)*5/9);
  }
  public void setCel(double cel){
    this.cel=cel;
  }
  public void getfar(){
    return ((cel*9/5)+32);
  }
  public void setfar(dofaruble far){
    this.cel=cel;
  }
```

}

Main method:

```
class A{
public static void main(String []args){
    Temp obj=new obj();
    obj.setcel(12.4);
    obj.setfar(34.5);
    System.out.println("Celcious"+obj.getcel());
    System.out.println("fahrenheit"+obj.getfar());
}
```

}